# Video Camera Image issue in iOS 10.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

Getting below issues on iOS 10.0.0 with xcode 8.0 mac os 10.12. It's working fine with iOS 9.3.5.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'videoCameraImage must be either video or audio'.

Please help me out on above issue.

Comment: please add code which you tried..

Comment: Have you included `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in plist?

Comment: Yes I have used camera,gallery & microphone access in plist. Still it crasehed on xcode 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to initiate the `UIImagePickerController` for your app.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController   *imagePickerController;
- (UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController {
    if (_imagePickerController == nil)  {
    _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    } 
    return _imagePickerController;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
}
```